# Windows narrator affects blender

Tags: modeling, windows

I know this may not really be a blender problem, but I have searched other forums and couldn't find anything useful, so I'm here.

While using Blender, if I use Ctrl + Alt + LMB in edit mode, instead of selecting edges in a given direction, it instead triggers Windows Narrator.

Is there anyone who knows how I can solve this problem? I know that in a worst-case scenario, I can remap the keymap, but I want that to be a last resort.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1325012 would something like this help?

Comment: No luck finding the menu. It seems Microsoft moved things around. I've been hopping form article to article, and I can't still find the key sequence editor.

Comment: You don't say what version of Windows you're using but is [Customizing Narrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/chapter-7-customizing-narrator-ce950246-c915-0d44-9be6-fb474387a285#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)  (Windows logo key  + Ctrl + N) any good?

Comment: My bad. I'm on Windows 11 22H2, and yes, I have tried your recommendation. I even disabled all the toggles in the narrator. Yet, nothing changed. It seems windows has more than one narrator service or it's just broken.

Comment: So, after a couple... a lot... of trial and error, I found out the problem was actually coming from the magnifier app.

I have low vision, so I sometimes have to use it. Unknown to me, it has its own built-in magnifier.

I changed the shortcut for the narrator to something else in the magnifier settings.

Thanks, everyone, for your help

Comment: Glad you're sorted!